# Java application using netbeans IDE 7.2

Tags: netbeans

So, I'm supposed to do a java application for an event management system,I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.2, I'm new to java so I designed a very simple GUI(drag and drop, all code is generated) of panels, buttons, labels and a tabbed pane with a couple lines of code in the generated source to link panels together through the buttons.

All that worked out just fine. Except for that when I build and run the package I don't see my GUI. What should I implement to run the app? The user simply clicks on buttons to navigate through the panels. I want the First panel appears whenever the project is built, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance.